# How to set up angular-cli with Visual Studio 2015 in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, angular-cli

I'm looking for some best practices and instructions on how to set up and integrate angular-cli (webpack) with Visual Studio 2015 in **MVC 5** (not Core).

I realize there's a similar question asked here ([how to set up asp.net angular 2 project using Angular-Cli with ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980192/how-to-set-up-asp-net-angular-2-project-using-angular-cli-with-asp-net-core-in-v)), but that was for Asp.net Core only. My project could not move over to Core yet due to server technical issues.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution:

1. Keep an empty index.html
2. Run ng build to generate index.html with scripts and styles links injected
3. Create a Gulp/Grunt task to extract all the scripts and styles links from index.html to a json file say manifest.json.(Here I use Cheerio and Gulp-asset-manifest )
4. Write logic to read manifest.json and output to your MVC views with Razor syntax

It works perfectly for my ASP.net MVC 5 project.

However it cannot work with route lazy load until publicPath is supported, because the url for chunk js files is loaded from root folder not dist folder.

For example:

The correct chunk js files should be:

www.example.com/MyApp/dist/[id].chunk.js

But it will load from:

www.example.com/MyApp/[id].chunk.js

I already created a PR to add pulishPath for angular-cli to solve this issue.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/3285

**Update:**

The PR for publicPath has been merged, lazy loading is no long an issue.

Comment: so your saying it is working or not working? suggesting you this link for lazy load http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643629/angularjs-dynamic-loading-of-script-files-using-lazyload-webpack/

Comment: @Aravind The topic is about angular 2 not angular 1

Comment: @ChangLiu Are you still using this approach two months in? How are you finding it?

Comment: @JMK Yes, I am still using this approach. I created it by myself

Comment: @ChangLiu Thanks, gonna give this a go later!

Comment: @ChangLiu As a newbie to Angular 2, can you provide some additional info on this setup. This is the only one I've seen that appears to work like I'd like. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

My approach to integrating Angular/CLI and MVC:
The idea here is to separate the front end development experience from the MVC part, so you don’t have to deal with any of the Visual Studio BS, and enjoy the benefits of the Angular CLI and VS Code.

My app is a hybrid app - most pages and main navigation is classic MVC, but some views are in fact single page applications, where the NG app is embedded into an existing view.

1. I created a new project in the solution to store the SPAs. (You can exclude this project from the solution build)
2. In the new project, I created a directory for each SPA. Each one of these folders is a standard CLI project (created using `ng new`)
3. Development of the ng stuff is done with **VS Code**, serving the app using `ng serve`. The development experience with VS Code is awesome!
4. When we want to embed the app into the MVC view, we first build it for prod using `ng build --prod`. This creates the bundles in the *dist* folder.
5. In the MVC app, I prepared a folder under *Scripts\Frontend* for each SPA
6. A *gulp task* in the MVC project is responsible for copying the bundles from the SPAs' *dist* folders into the appropriate folders under *Scripts\Frontend*. Using Task Runner, the task was bound to to Before Build, so it is automatically executed whenever the app is built.
   The important gulp command is:

   ```
   gulp.src('../FrontEndProj/spa1/dist/*bundle.*')
       .pipe(gulp.dest('Scripts/Frontend/spa1'));
   ```

   of course, you need to delete the existing files etc.
7. In bundles config, I've created a bundle for the styles and a bundle for the scripts. Since prod bundle names are generated with hash by the CLI, I use wildcards:

   ```
   bundles.add(new script("~/Scripts/spa1/js")
     .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Frontend/spa1", inline.*")
     .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Frontend/spa1", "polyfills.*")
     .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Frontend/spa1", "vendor.*")
     .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Frontend/spa1", "main.*"));
   ```

   (Note that the order you add the files to the bundle is important!)

   ```
   bundles.add(
     new StyleBundle("/Scripts/spa1.css")
       .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Frontend/spa1", "*.css")
   ```
8. In your view, add the ng app directive and use the bundles:

   ```
   @section head {
     @Styles.Render("~Scripts/spa1/css")
   }

   <app-root>Loading...</app-root>

   @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/spa1/js")
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I use a slightly different approach to Chang Liu.
After I run ng build -- prod, I copy the files to the root folder,and change the href attribute in index.html to correspond to my IIS virtual directory.