# AngularJS- Dynamic Loading of script files using LazyLoad- Webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack, lazy-loading, oclazyload

Right now in my `index.html` page I have links to two CDN files one being a JS and the other a CSS file.

i.e.
in the the bottom of my body

```
https://somedomain.com/files/js/js.min.js
```

and in the head

```
https://somedomain.com/files/css/css.min.css
```

But right now they aren't needed on my homepage but just in one particular route. So I was looking into how I can lazy load these CDN resources when that routes gets hit i.e. `/profile` and only then ?

These aren't installed via bower or npm but just loaded via CDN url for example jquery. How in Angular 1 and Webpack can I lazy load that based on a route ?

Comment: By **one particular route** what does it refer to?

Comment: Angular has route i.e /profile. Profile has a seperate Module, Controller, view etc I only want to load the above libraries when a user navigates to that particular route.

Comment: $ocLazyLoad works great

Comment: $ocLazyLoad Example app http://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-lazy-load-modules-controllers-angularjs/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you go.. It is made possible using **oclazyload**. Have a look at below code. A plunker linked below

I have a module Called **myApp** as below

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','oc.lazyLoad'])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state("home", {
                    url: "/home",
                    templateUrl: "Home.html",
                    controller: 'homeCtrl',
                    resolve: { 
                        loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                            return $ocLazyLoad.load('homeCtrl.js');
                        }]
                    }
                })
            .state("profile", {
                url:"/profile",
                templateUrl: "profile.html",
                 resolve: {
                      loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                      return $ocLazyLoad.load('someModule.js');
                        }]
                    }
            })

    });
```

I have another module called **someApp** as below

```
(function () {
var mynewapp=angular.module('someApp',['myApp']);

mynewapp.config(function(){

  //your code to route from here! 

});
      mynewapp.controller("profileCtrl", function ($scope) {

            console.log("reached profile controller");
        });

})();
```

I have a Live Plunker for your demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/nkg9Xw)

Answer (score 2):

I have this [JStaticLoader](https://github.com/chozzz/JStaticLoader) repo, to ease me loading static files whenever I need them. Though, it's not angularized, but you can still use it in your app as a `directive`, direct call it from your `controller` or even in the `$rootScope` to load your desired `js`.

`JStaticLoader` uses pure js and require no dependencies. It uses `XMLHttpRequest` to load the static files.

As an example use in your `app.js` (on `$routeChangeStart` or `$stateChangeStart`)

```
myApp
.run(['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http) {
    var scriptExists = function (scriptId) {
        if (document.getElementById(scriptId)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    };

    var addLazyScript = function (scriptId, url) {
        if (scriptExists(scriptId)) return;

        var js = document.createElement('script'),
            els = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

        js.id = scriptId;
        js.src = url;
        js.type = "text/javascript";

        els.parentNode.insertBefore(js, els);
    };

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (e, current) {
        if (current.controller === 'MainCtrl') {
            var pathUrls = ["https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.js"],
                scriptId = 'lazyScript1';

            if (scriptExists(scriptId)) return;

            JStaticLoader(pathUrls, { files: ['js'] }, function (vals, totalTime) {
                /* Success */
                for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
                    var path = vals[i];
                    addLazyScript(scriptId, path);
                }
            }, function (error, totalTime) {
                /* Error */
                console.warn(error, totalTime);
            });
        }
    });
}]);
```

On the sample above, I get a `js` file by using xhr, and append it as a `script` in my `document` once it's finished. The script will then be loaded from your browser's cache.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is not an external library.. it's actually as built in as can get https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest. By implement it on your own, do you mean like... implementing ajax without using XMLHttpRequest? sorry to be blunt but.. what a terrible idea!

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I am not saying XHR is external library.. But, `JStaticLoader` is..

Comment: ... I must have been mislead by this sentence: "*It's using XMLHttpRequest to load them. So, if you do not wish to use external library for this, you can implement it your own.*" At first (and actually, many read afterwards too) and without surrounding context, it totally means that XMLHttpRequest is an external library, and that if you don't want to use those, you should implement your own. Maybe just remove that part about XHR and just say that JStaticLoader is, and that if you want to avoid external libraries, you should implement it yourself.

Comment: which, thinking about it, means you could also just remove that altogether, as the point is to provide answer, not to tell op they can implement it on their own... :)

Answer (score 2):

*Strictly talking about the Webpack* -

> **Webpack is just a module bundler and not a javascript loader.Since it packages files only from the local storage and doesn't load the files from the web(except its own chunks).ALthough other modules may be included into the webpack which may do the same process.**

I will demonstrate only some of the modules which you can try,as there are many such defined on the web.

Therefore a better way to lazy load the cdn from the another domain would be using the *javascript loader - [script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js)*

It can be loaded in the following way -

```
var $script = require("script.js");
 $script = ("https://somedomain.com/files/js/js.min.js or https://somedomain.com/files/css/css.min.css",function(){
 //.... is ready now
});
```

This is possible because the *script-loader* just evaluates the javascript in the global context.

References [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/150)

*Concerning about the issue of lazy loading the cdn into the angular app*

The following library [Lab JS](https://github.com/getify/LABjs) is made specifically for this purpose.
It becomes very simple to load and bloack the javascript using this library.

Here is an example to demonstrate

```
<script src="LAB.js"></script>
  <script>
    $LAB
     .script("/local/init.js").wait(function(){
       waitfunction();
     });
  <script>
```

**OR**

You can use the [require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html)

Here is an example to load the jquery

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min"
    },
    waitSeconds: 40
  });
```

*You should also consider the following paragraph from [this](http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/why-loading-third-party-scripts-async-is-not-good-enough) article.*

> Loading third party scripts async is key for having high performance web pages, but those scripts still block onload. Take the time to analyze your web performance data and understand if and how those not-so-important content/widgets/ads/tracking codes impact page load times.