# changes to json file are not reflectled in the console logs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the following file structure:

```sh
├─ log.js
├─ test.js
└─ file.json
```

`log.js` exports a function that logs the contents of `file.json` like :

```js
// log.js
exports.logFile = () => {
    console.log(require('./file.json'));
};
```

I'm calling this function every second in `test.js` like so:

```js
// test.js
setInterval(() => {
    require('./log.js').logFile();
}, 1000);
```

Now, when I change `file.json` while `log.js` is running, none of my changes are reflected in the logs, i.e. it keeps printing the same (initial) value every second.

I fail to understand why this is happening, shouldn't it show the changes?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588279/node-js-caching-json

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40946522/how-to-reload-a-required-module-at-runtime. I think it relates to your question. The file is already loaded, so it makes little sense for JS to reload it each iteration as that would be very inefficient.

Comment: require() caches everything it loads...