# Inject lazy loaded controller into app

Tags: angularjs, oclazyload

I am trying to register a controller that I load dynamically thanks to ocLoazyLoad.

Once I have loaded the JS file, how to I tell the app that there is a new controller ?

I am doing this inside a controller (when loading a modal, I load the corresponding controller...)

I tried to play around with `$controllerProvider` but nothing worked.

Comment: did you read the docs? can't find your problem there?

Comment: I can't say that I read all the docs but I did read as much as I could and couldn't find a suitable example. Can you help me ?

Comment: can't you using `$stateProvider` and load the controller with `resolve` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS- Dynamic Loading of script files using LazyLoad- Webpack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643629/angularjs-dynamic-loading-of-script-files-using-lazyload-webpack)