# How to make a loading (spin) while requesting to server by $http on angularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

```
$http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    transformRequest: function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for(var p in obj)
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        return str.join("&");
    },
      data: {
      }
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
          // this callback will be called asynchronously
          // when the response is available

        if(response.data == 'true'){
            swal("Good job!", "New case has been created", "success");
        }
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
```

I want to show a progress bar or spin on bootstrap while http request on angularjs

Comment: You could add a loading div or img and then put an `ng-if` attribute on it, setting some `showLoader` variable in your `$scope` to `true` just before you start your request, and then set to `false` on success or error.

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Comment: Yes it was helpful, thank you so much

Comment: @Aravind Can you answer for my another question  ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532079/how-to-load-css-by-using-requirejs
Thanks for your support man

Comment: @ShabeebCk you already have an answer there! you want my solution still?

Comment: @Aravind I ams till looking for solution, its very hard to find tutorial for require-css on web :(

Comment: instead of requirejs I would rather suggest you with this solution of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643629/angularjs-dynamic-loading-of-script-files-using-lazyload-webpack/40688693#40688693 still if you need requirejs to be fixed I can work on it for u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugessting you to use this **[angular-loading-bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar)**

Steps

1. Include the script references and css as mentioned in the above
   github, you can use cdn as well as mentioned.
2. Add these two functions in your controller

   ```
   $scope.start = function() {
     cfpLoadingBar.start();
   };

   $scope.complete = function () {
      cfpLoadingBar.complete();
   }
   ```
3. Include the `'angular-loading-bar', 'ngAnimate'` as dependencies.
4. Add the below code for the app configurations

   - If you are looking for the progress bar

     ```
     app.config(['cfpLoadingBarProvider', function(cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = false;
     }])
     ```
   - If you are looking for a spinner

     ```
     app.config(['cfpLoadingBarProvider', function(cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = true;
     }])
     ```
5. Finally, In your **$http** request call the `$scope.start()` function and in your success method call the `$scope.complete()`

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q8ZfrYk3sa6KDuDebMzi?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

A simple way:

html:

```
<div class="spinner" ng-show="loading"></div>
```

js :

```
$scope.loading = true
$http.post(...).then(function(response){
  $scope.data = response.data // or whatever you needs...
  $scope.loading = false
},function(){
  $scope.loading = false
  console.log("error")
})
```

If you want to generalize, you can also have a look to http interceptor : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors