# How to load css by using requirejs?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, oclazyload

This is my requirejs config file. I'm using require js on my angular based project. If I could load css with `requirejs` I would be able to organize my css files too! I'm new to `requirejs` concept. Any help appreciated

```
require.config({
    paths:{
        'angular'       : "agular",
        'app'           : 'app',
        'coreModel'     : 'coreModel',
        'test'          : 'controller/test'
    },
    shim: {
        'app' : {
            deps :['angular','coreModel',]
        },

        'coreModel' : {
            deps : ['angular','test']
        },
        'test' : {
            deps : ['angular',]
        }
    },
});

require(['app',],function(){
    angular.bootstrap(document,['app']);
});
```

This is my main controller

```
define(function(){

    var coreModel = angular.module('coreModel',['test']);

    coreModel.controller('mainController',function($scope){
        $scope.test = "Hello World";
    });
});
```

How can I load css with requirejs ?

Comment: is there any simple documentation or tutorial on web for require-css ? ,

Comment: https://github.com/guybedford/require-css/tree/master/example

Comment: @lin thanks, it was helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rather suggest you to something different using a ocLazyLoad.

Reference to my answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643629/angularjs-dynamic-loading-of-script-files-using-lazyload-webpack/40688693#40688693)**

Follow the initial steps of the above link for configuration

I would suggest you to use this way in your Controller file as below

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp').controller("homeCtrl", function ($ocLazyLoad,$scope) {

          //this line loads your styles and apply it 
          $ocLazyLoad.load('style.css');

});
})();
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xwj3X1?p=preview)**

Note: In the demo click on the menu- > click home

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Comment: Oh yea, this is much better!

Comment: doesn't answer OP

Comment: @catbadger then what is answer to OP?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the [requirejs documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html):

> Since knowing when the file has loaded is not reliable, it does not
>   make sense to explicitly support CSS files in RequireJS loading, since
>   it will lead to bug reports due to browser behavior. If you do not
>   care when the file is loaded, you can easily write your own function
>   to load CSS on demand by doing the following:

```
function loadCss(url) {
    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.type = "text/css";
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
}
```

---

But you can use [requirecss](https://github.com/guybedford/require-css) to make it work as simple as `requirejs` does:

- Install require-css with `bower install require-css`
- Configurate your application

  ```
  map: {
    '*': {
      'css': 'require-css/css' // or whatever the path to require-css is
    }
  }
  ```
- Add your files for requirecss like you did it in requirejs

  ```
  define(['css!styles/main'], function() {
     //code that requires the stylesheet: styles/main.css
  });
  ```