# when button disabled to enable calling function to show progressBar in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

Form is empty, submit button dissabled, when user selected all input field submit button now dissable to enable that status change that time I need to call function to show progressbar.I tried bellow code.

```
html
----

<html>
<body>
{{message}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you could add `ng-if` with flag on progressbar `div` and then on submit button click show that `div`

Comment: Do you want to disable submit button when you are showing progress bar? I'm not getting your question

Comment: That because you are not calling progressBarShow() function anywhere in your code. what time you want to call the ProgressBarShow()? Is it on radio button change or Any change inside your form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a loading (spin) while requesting to server by $http on angularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053302/how-to-make-a-loading-spin-while-requesting-to-server-by-http-on-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

You can check form validation on progress bar if form is valid then display progress bar

HTML Code

```
<style>
  button.st{
  padding:5px ;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  /* background:green; */
  /* border:1px solid lightblue; */
/*   color:darkblue; */
  margin:10px;
}
.progressbar{
  border:1px solid #fff;padding:10px;border-radius:1px;width:60%;margin:10px;background:#999;color:red;
}
p{
  margin-left:10px;
}
</style>
  <body >
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<p progressbar prog="form1.$valid ? '50':'10'" ></p>


<form name="form1" novalidate>
  <p>
       <span style="color:blue">1) select One</span><br/>
       <input type="radio" ng-model="user.q1" name="grp1" value="A" ng-required="true"/>A
       <input type="radio" ng-model="user.q1" name="grp1" value="B" ng-required="true"/>B
       <input type="radio" ng-model="user.q1" name="grp1" value="C" ng-required="true"/>C
  </p>
  <p>
       <span style="color:blue">2) select two</span><br/>
       <input type="radio" ng-model="user.q2" name="grp2" value="A" ng-required="true"/>A
       <input type="radio" ng-model="user.q2" name="grp2" value="B" ng-required="true"/>B
       <input type="radio" ng-model="user.q2" name="grp2" value="C" ng-required="true"/>C
       </p>
    <button class="st" ng-disabled="form1.$invalid"> submit</button>
  </p>
</form>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Controller js Code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
   $scope.name = 'pelase select all fileds';
    $scope.progressBar = false;
    $scope.progressbarShow = function(){
     $scope.progressBar = true;
    }
});
app.directive('progressbar', [function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        'progress': '=prog'
    },
    template: '<div class="stripe" style="background-color: #C7D2D2; height:30px; width:100%;"> <div  ng-style="style" style="background-color:#8CD211; height:100%"></div> </div>',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {       
     $scope.$watch(function() {
            $scope.style = {"width": $scope.progress + "%"}
        })
    }
}
```

}])

please check working plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/y35BnTUG36ChnCSC2YYH?p=preview

Comment: the issue in your custom directive please fixed this then it display

Comment: i have change my plnkr code please check it work for you

Comment: still not clear your requirment please check this plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/y35BnTUG36ChnCSC2YYH?p=preview

Comment: Just add ng-show in p tag    <p progressbar prog="form1.$valid ? '50':'10'"  ng-show="form1.$valid"></p>

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) on $scope.user to watch change in radio buttons

```
 $scope.$watch("user", function() {
      if(!angular.isUndefined($scope.user.q1) && !angular.isUndefined($scope.user.q2))
      $scope.increaseProgress = 50;
    }, true);
```

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("main", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.user={};
    $scope.increaseProgress = 10;
    $scope.progressBarShow = function() {
      alert("Coming");
      $scope.increaseProgress = 50;
    }

    $scope.$watch("user", function() {
      if(angular.isUndefined($scope.user.q1) && angular.isUndefined($scope.user.q2))
      $scope.increaseProgress = 50;
    }, true);
  }])
  .directive('progressbar', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        'progress': '=progressbar'
      },
      template: '<div class="stripe" style="background-color: #442; height:50px; width:100%;"> <div  ng-style="style" style="background-color:#CD2; height:100%"></div> </div>',
      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $scope.$watch(function() {
          $scope.style = {
            "width": $scope.progress + "%"
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
  <div progressbar="increaseProgress" ng-show="form1.$valid"></div>
  <form name="form1" novalidate>
    <p>
      <span style="color:blue">1) select One</span>
      <br/>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="user.q1" name="grp1" value="A" ng-required="true" />A
      <input type="radio" ng-model="user.q1" name="grp1" value="B" ng-required="true" />B
      <input type="radio" ng-model="user.q1" name="grp1" value="C" ng-required="true" />C
    </p>
    <p>
      <span style="color:blue">2) select two</span>
      <br/>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="user.q2" name="grp2" value="A" ng-required="true" />A
      <input type="radio" ng-model="user.q2" name="grp2" value="B" ng-required="true" />B
      <input type="radio" ng-model="user.q2" name="grp2" value="C" ng-required="true" />C
    </p>
    <button class="st" ng-disabled="form1.$invalid"> submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```