# how to use Angular CLI Project Template in ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, angular, asp.net-core, angular-cli, marketplace

I found a marketplace template(Angular CLI Project Template) for creating and configuring an Angular CLI project in Visual Studio.
When I download and install `.VSIX` file from the marketplace, the error:

`The extension cannot be installed to this product due to prerequisites that cannot be resolved` appears.

I have installed Visual Studio 2017, Node.js and Angular CLI on my computer.

I know that there are many manual configurations for matching Angular CLI with ASP.NET Core but this template seems to work as same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just run the [Angular CLI Project Template vsix](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreyFomin.AngularCLIProjectTemplate) installer and all works fine for me.
If you check the [source.extension.vsixmanifest](https://github.com/andfomin/NgProjectTemplate/blob/5b9f4249b8a9857c6badbea22aaae63449a4aa39/AfominDotCom.NgProjectTemplate/source.extension.vsixmanifest#L25) `Prerequisites` section you will  see:

```
<Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[15.0,16.0)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />
<Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet" Version="[15.0.26208.0,16.0)" DisplayName="NuGet package manager" />
<Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web" Version="[15.0.26323.1,16.0)" DisplayName="ASP.NET and web development tools" />
```

Just try to install the ones you are missing and I think you should be fine after then. In order to do that you need to update your visual studio 2017 or get missed components installed.

FYI my visual studio 2017 version looking like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank @Kuncevic. my Visual Studio version is 15.can I update just three components?

Comment: Run installer and make sure you have required components like Web Dev checked and installed. If it is already installed make sure you have your visual studio updated.

Comment: Found this helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-visual-studio to learn how to update VS 2017.

Comment: go here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826352/angular-cli-in-asp-net-core-2-angular-template/46877822#46877822