# The command "npm run build -- --prod" exited with code 1 error

Tags: angular, npm, asp.net-core, angular-cli, npm-install

I'm developing an Asp.Net Core 2 and Angular 5 project in visual studio 2017.

When I'm going to publish my project then the error '**The command "npm run build -- --prod" exited with code 1**' show in error list window.
I created the project with [Angular CLI in ASP.NET Core 2 Angular template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48972840/7487135)
 link and everything was fine and the project run and publish correctly.
After a while, I don't know what exactly happens that cause the project doesn't publish.

In the npm-debug.log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build',
1 verbose cli   '--',
1 verbose cli   '--prod' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.10.3
4 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Project\JWS\JWSApplication\package.json'
4 verbose stack     at Error (native)
5 verbose cwd C:\Project\JWS\JWSApplication
6 error Windows_NT 10.0.15063
7 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build" "--" "--prod"
8 error node v6.10.3
9 error npm  v3.10.10
10 error path C:\Project\JWS\JWSApplication\package.json
11 error code ENOENT
12 error errno -4058
13 error syscall open
14 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Project\JWS\JWSApplication\package.json'
15 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Project\JWS\JWSApplication\package.json'
15 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
15 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
16 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

Comment: Try npm run build - - prod

Comment: @Praveen Kumar. I updated the NodeJS and the 'npm run build - - prod' command didn't fix the problem.

Comment: remove bower_components and run npm install

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Perform any of the following options as long as there is an error

1. For passing an argument to build command:

   **change 'npm run build -- --prod' to 'npm run build --prod' in the .csproj file**
2. Open ClientApp folder and Update project angular-cli with this CMD command:

   **npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest**
3. Update visual studio NodeJS and npm from:

   `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Package Management > External 
    Web Tools`

If NodeJS and npm aren't installed on your environment path Add NodeJS and npm folder to the top of the list else move $(path) to the top of the list

[image].

Thank @Praveen Kumar and @Yerkon

Comment: I also encountered the same issue and step 1 worked for me.  Thanks, this saves me much time.

Comment: VS 2017, 15.8.1, .net core 2 Angular Template: still had to apply thix fix. Thanks! Don't get it why Microsoft won't fix it.

Comment: Where do you put this "npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest" ? i've open .angular-cli.json but i didn't find the npm install string.

Comment: @Mr.Developer. Open CMD in the clientApp folder and run the npm install... command.

Comment: @ImanBahrampour i've alredy done it, but on the .angular-cli.json i don't find this string npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest

Comment: @Mr.Developer. the 'install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest' is a cmd command and update angular CLI of a project. the angular-cli.json is about project configuration and 'install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest' command does not exist there.

Comment: At my end it worked when I updated to VS 2019 and changed csproj to  'npm run build --prod'. Surprisingly it did not help when I was running on VS 2017.

Comment: **be aware**, when removing the first two `--` from `npm run build -- --prod`! The additional `--` are telling npm that anything after this **should be appended directly to the command itself** as stated here: [link](https://corgibytes.com/blog/2017/04/18/npm-tips/)

Comment: VS19 adding --prod at the end of the command. So if the script says npm run build --prod, it will become npm run build -- --prod

Comment: change 'npm run build -- --prod' to 'npm run build --prod' in the .csproj file : this part was enough for me. Super Thanks

Comment: Step 1 fixed things for me! @ImanBahrampour Thanks from my heart!

Answer (score 14):

Got same error, my environment:

```
.NET Core 2.1 RC-1
Angular v5.2.4
NPM v5.7.1
Node v8.11.2
```

And nothing mentioned above did not helped.
Simple go to ".\ClientApp" //Angula-CLI project and run

```
npm run build
```

then you will see real errors - so that means simple you have some errors in code, so fix angular UI code and it will build fine :).

Comment: This was my real problem, relying on VS to make build don't point really where code problems are on angular Framework that only pops up when running ng build --prod

Comment: The question is about "npm run build -- --prod" error not real errors.

Comment: Before insert any answer it's better to read the question carefully. The 'npm run build -- --prod' exist in the .csproj file and doesn't related to 'npm run build'. you must fix the 'npm run build -- --prod' error.

Answer (score 14):

Run:

`npm run build:prod -- --prod`

to see the actual error/errors that caused your build to fail.

Update: the new command is:

`npm run build -- --configuration production`

Comment: where does this "build:prod"-script come from?

Answer (score 3):

Check this maybe you have problem with lack of memory

```
 "build": "node --max-old-space-size=4069 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
```

Answer (score 3):

**`Error: The command "npm install" exited with code 1`**

Add environment variable, right click this PC

- Go to Properties
- Go to Advance tab
- Click environment variable
- In User variable section click new, Enter variable name "Path" and value `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm`
- One more - In User variable section click new, Enter variable name "Path" and value `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

If **`Path`** variable already there, then you can edit that variable add new path(value) by **`;`** separation.

Answer (score 2):

if deploying on **netlify**, use below command instead of **`npm run build`** while in site setting build & deploy.

**`CI= npm run build`**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in command line NodeJS version of Visual Studio is old. In your command output we can see:

**node@v6.10.3**

Update `NodeJS`

Comment: I updated from visual studio 'External WEB Tools' section

Answer (score 1):

Try running: ng build "prod" and see what the actual error is.

Comment: As mentioned in the accepted answer, the 'npm run build --prod' fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the error in your output window, it seems that the npm build command is targeting the wrong directory and cannot find the **package.json** file to perform its build:

```
11 error code ENOENT
12 error errno -4058
13 error syscall open
14 error enoent ENOENT: **no such file or directory, open** 'C:\Project\JWS\JWSApplication\package.json'
15 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\Project\JWS\JWSApplication\package.json'
15 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
15 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
16 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

I suspect your msbuild is targeting your root project folder instead of your **ClientApp/SpaRoot** folder where your package.json file will be located.(Guess based on similar experience since I do not have access to your .csproj to inspect your msbuild configurations).

If you open your .csproj file, you should see where the **ClientApp/SpaRoot** file is located. Ideally, it will be something like below:

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
        <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Based on the above, the directory path to your **ClientApp/SpaRoot** folder will be configured which contains the **package.json** file and will be used when calling `npm build` during deployment:

```
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
        <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
        <Exec **WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)"** Command="npm install" />
        <Exec **WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)"** Command="npm run build --prod" />
        <Exec **WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)"** Command="npm run build:ssr --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />
        
        <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
        <ItemGroup>
            <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
            <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
            <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
                <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
                <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
                <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
            </ResolvedFileToPublish>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed 'npm run build -- --prod' to 'npm run build --prod' in the .csproj file but publish did not work correctly and my codes in live became open and it wasn't true. I made the following change in the angular.json file.(maximumWarning and maximumError: I increased the size)
"budgets": [
{
"type": "initial",
"maximumWarning": "8mb",
"maximumError": "16mb"
},
{
"type": "anyComponentStyle",
"maximumWarning": "8kb",
"maximumError": "16kb"
}
]
and then npm run build -- --prod worked!

Comment: Look into formatting on SO....it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to angular.json file, configurations->production->budgets, increase maximumWarning and maximumError more than the error is showing.

```
"budgets": [
        {
          "type": "initial",
          "maximumWarning": "12mb",
          "maximumError": "12mb"
        }
      ]
```