# Angular 9.0 SSR is compiled, but I cannot publish it on the server

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal, angular9

I updated my Angular 8 project to Angular 9. I ran the command “npm run build: ssr && npm run serve: ssr”. It worked flawlessly and “browser” and “server” folders were created in the “dist” folder.

I uploaded these files to my server (Plesk panel). I set it to read server / main.js file with node.js.

It failed because it could not find “browser / index.html” in “dist” folder. I created a folder called “dist” and moved the “browser” folder into it.

Then it timed out, my project did not work. I run Node.js in development mode to see the error, but it says there is a timeout.

server.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

const domino = require('domino'); // kb
const fs = require('fs'); // kb
const template = fs.readFileSync('dist/browser/index.html').toString(); // kb
const win = domino.createWindow(template); // kb
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
global["branch"] = null;
global["object"] = win.object;
global['DOMTokenList'] = win.DOMTokenList;
global['Node'] = win.Node;
global['Text'] = win.Text;
global['HTMLElement'] = win.HTMLElement;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

main.server.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
export {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';

export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.server.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app-server",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "./src/app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "kodumunblogu",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile:server_bak": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "build:ssr_bak": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "serve:ssr_bak": "node dist/server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles_bak": "ng build --prod --aot && ng run kodumunblogu:server:production --bundleDependencies all",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run kodumunblogu:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run kodumunblogu:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run kodumunblogu:prerender",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.15",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.7.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.7.2",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.3.1",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^9.0.0",
    "@ngx-share/button": "^7.1.2",
    "@ngx-share/buttons": "^7.1.2",
    "@ngx-share/core": "^7.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^9.0.0-rc.4",
    "quill": "^1.3.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.3",
    "tslint": "~5.14.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem did you find a solution?

Comment: @tfa Unfortunately I haven't found a solution yet. I think it was caused by the server. Because it works locally.

Comment: Did you find any solution. I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-make sure in your "Document Root" to choose the browser folder not server.

-in your server.ts REMOVE this if condition:

```
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}
```

and replace it with just:

```
run();
```

then restart your node.js app again from the plesk GUI

Comment: What is the different Shreef ?

Comment: actually, I don't know, it just worked like that :D 
but for some reason this is always false "moduleFilename === __filename" so the condition doesn't happen

Answer (score 0):

I doubt tsconfig.json file baseUrl is the issue. You may remove the same and try once in local then server.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately when I delete the baseUrl definition, it is also Time-out. Localhost: Works smoothly over 4000. But it does not work on the server.

Answer (score -1):

These are the steps that I got Angular 9 with .net core 3.1 all working using Angular Universal and NodeIIS.

This can get you started https://medium.com/@MarkPieszak/angular-universal-server-side-rendering-deep-dive-dc442a6be7b7.

Note my final project is not pre-rendered it is ssr meaning certain pages have parameters and will keep growing over time so I can't pre-render (cache) certain pages it needs to be ssr.

I created an angular app within VS .net core and added universal. Then after you can run ng serve make sure you can run the following on your angular 9 app.

1. ng run YOURAPPNAME:server:production --bundleDependencies true
2. npm run build:ssr
3. npm run serve:ssr

Note make sure your code will work for ssr

**Fix Angular JS code to work for SSR**

1. change all code for localstorage e.g.  if
   (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) { }
2. Google global['window'],
   global['document'] and app.use(cors()); for server.ts as you will
   need to set these up too.

**Server stuff**

1. look at the solution here for c# .net core for getting cors working https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5162494/Currently-I-am-working-on-angular-and-web-API-NET
2. Follow steps above to remove -- on both lines and I used published wizard straight to IIS from VS (it copies a folder in the root containing lots of Dlls etc, a ClientApp folder that contains dist and a node_modules) See publish does all the hard work for you. If your doing this manually you copy entire contents from debug...\publish folder. I did not even have to mess around with the web.config file. Once it published and I setup domain to point to that folder in IIS.
3. install nodeiis and run npm run serve:ssr which will process all requests for website and translate to ssr - best to use pm2 (npm i pm2)
4. I added this to the VS net core SPA startup

   ```
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
       {
           spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4000");

           spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

           if (env.IsDevelopment())
           {
               spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
           }
       });
   ```

When testing locally I can run ng serve and change localhost to 4200 and then when I run npm run serve:ssr I can change to 4000 and you can refresh you website and see how it renders differently

**Notes**

- Here is my frontend code working shows how i setup resolve to make sure the content is loaded correctly for seo - [Angular SSR Refresh/Load Page Pending Api Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611378/angular-ssr-refresh-load-page-pending-api-call)
- You may need to setup angular side cors too if you get preflight error - https://medium.com/@alexxsanya/fix-cors-in-angular-8-using-cli-proxy-configuration-787589f06f94

I wish they made it easier but after all these steps it works and the website loads instantly. When I look at the page title using view source its the index title but Google Webmasters has read the correct title on all pages.

**Alternative Solution**

There is a paid service called prerender.io I was going to use them costs about €9 a month and can implement easy https://github.com/dingyuliang/prerender-dotnet/wiki/Prerender-Middleware-for-ASP.NET-Core. I used it for an angularJS project and it works fine.

Hope these steps helps someone as it took me ages to get this working