# Can't build project from cloned repo

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, visual-studio, npm

Recently started working on a new project. I have cloned the repo and ran NPM install to acquire all the needed dependencies. When I try to build the project I get two errors.

Error # 1:
The command "npm run build&&npm run vendor" exited with code1.

Error #2:
Cannot find module './dist/vendor-manifest.json'

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 with a fresh install of Windows & nodejs

I have tried implementing the solution from this post : [The command "npm run build -- --prod" exited with code 1 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643536/the-command-npm-run-build-prod-exited-with-code-1-error)

However I have not had much success

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/99

Comment: `Execute webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js before run application.`