# Angular CLI on .net Core 2.0

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to activate angular CLI on a .net core 2.0 app. I want to use Internationalization features but for this, I need to run CLI commands. So I followed this guide: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1208529/Angular-CLI-and-ASP-NET-Core-Angular-Template

But this does not work for me. The moment I hit step 6 where I need to create a project to get the .angular-cli.json file it just starts spitting out warnings and errors like a minigun on steroids.

It says it cannot find a lot of files or directories and that an operation is not permitted.

Here are some pictures:
[image]

[image]

It says I need to do this step to get a .angular-cli.json.

If anyone could help me out to install the angular-cli into the project that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

U can use the "Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates".
I describe this template in the following link:

[Angular CLI in ASP.NET Core 2 Angular template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48972840/7487135)